# How to type non-printable ASCII characters in Mac OS X Terminal?

Tags: macos, telnet, ascii

To communicate with a serial-type device over a telnet socket, I need to type the null character (ASCII 0) and all other non-printable ASCII characters.

On Windows, you hold ALT and type the ASCII code.

How do I do this on Mac OS X?

Comment: [Type null character in terminal](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7572801/995714)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> sends ASCII NUL.

For the general case, *System Preferences > Keyboard > Input Sources*, scroll down the list and select *Unicode Hex Input*.

[image]

You can then use <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> (and, if you disable Spotlight's use of it, <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>) to switch between input modes or assign it a keyboard shortcut of its own (and presumably another to switch back) in *System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts*.

Once Unicode Hex Input is enabled, you hold down <kbd>Option</kbd> and type the 4 digit hex code; on releasing <kbd>Option</kbd> it should be typed.  You could stay in that mode as long as you don't need any characters beyond `U+007F` (or of course type them all with hex input instead of, say, <kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> <kbd>e</kbd> to type `é`).

Comment: Great, thanks!  Note to others: on my system, the default shortcut key was Option Cmd Space.

Comment: For Mac OS X it's Shift + Alt + Space

Comment: In my case, I had to enter a `DLE` character (Unicode 0x10) onto the command-line. `DLE` is the same thing as `Ctrl-P` which, in any program that uses `readline` sees as a "scroll to previous entry" command, so it's the same thing as pressing `↑`. In order to type a `DLE` character on my terminal, I had to do `Ctrl-V` then `Opt-0-0-1-0` and I got a character that looks on the screen like `^P`.

Answer (score 2):

In many CLI/TUI applications you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> in order to tell the application to accept the next keypress as raw character codes instead of invoking its normal function.